# How To Get The Value Of Array, But Without Index

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 1, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 17, 1, 28000));
```

and I want to group together the `product_id ($order_list[2])` based on `vendor_id ($order_list[1])` and I did it. it looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 8
                    [pcs] => 1
                    [weight] => 115.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 17
                    [pcs] => 1
                    [weight] => 120.00
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [pcs] => 10
                    [weight] => 250.00
                )

        )

)
```

now the problem is...

how to get the value of this new array while the index of this new array contains `vendor_id`?

I'm expecting 1 or 6 as result of `$new_array[0]` and `$new_array[1]` respectively. so I can create `for` loop. is it still possible to get that? thanks before.

UPDATE : I have this code get the value :

```
foreach ($order_array as $value) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($value);
}
```

but, unfortunately I get this output as result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [pcs] => 1
            [weight] => 115.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17
            [pcs] => 1
            [weight] => 120.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [pcs] => 10
            [weight] => 250.00
        )

)
```

I still can't get `1` and `6` :-(

Comment: where is your vendorid?

Comment: try to use foreach loop instead of for loop

Comment: @yahoo : vendor_id ($order_list[1]), it has value 1 and 6 in this case

Comment: @Nikunj : foreach loop only get the value of each `vendor_id` array. doesn't get the value of `vendor_id` itself. check my update above.

Comment: You add the key into your `foreach` like `foreach($order_array as $id => $value)` and the vendor id is `$id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add key field in foreach loop:

```
$order_list = Array
(
    1 => Array
    (
        0 => Array
        (
            'product_id' => 8,
            'pcs' => 1,
            'weight' => 115.00
        ),

        1 => Array
        (
            'product_id' => 17,
            'pcs' => 1,
            'weight' => 120.00
        )

    ),

    6 => Array
    (
        0 => Array
        (
            'product_id' => 2,
            'pcs' => 10,
            'weight' => 250.00
        )

    )

);

foreach ($order_list as $vendor_id => $value) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo "Vendor Id: " . $vendor_id . '<br />';
    print_r($value);
}
```

**output:**

```
Vendor Id: 1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [pcs] => 1
            [weight] => 115
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17
            [pcs] => 1
            [weight] => 120
        )

)
Vendor Id: 6
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [pcs] => 10
            [weight] => 250
        )

)
```